# How can i implicitly convert my class to another type?

Tags: c#, .net, operators, implicit

For example implicitly

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
int i = myClass;
```

Comment: From his other questions my guess is .net...

Comment: Yes :) .I think this time there is no answer to my question because we can't edit closed source classes so we can't implement implicit operator for them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I implicitly convert another struct to my Type ? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015527/how-can-i-implicitly-convert-another-struct-to-my-type)

Comment: Why do you want to? In my 8 years of working in .NET, not once have I ever done this. If you can't alter the class, you can always add a ToInt() extension method. Sure it's more verbose, but I generally like knowing what is going on.

Comment: I am sorry :).
1) To be courious is most important thing for programmer
2) As u said using such operators makes code more clarity.
3) I am on the way which research benefit of using it.If u can't try so u can't know exactly how it helps.

Comment: @Matt - There are many times that this is useful. The problem is that it can be abused.

Comment: XName use implicit convert for string and this makes much more easy job.for example new XElement("person") instead of XElement(new XName("person"))

Comment: @Freshblood - That is actually a perfect example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to define this in the `MyClass` file.

```
public static implicit operator int(MyClass instance) 
{
    if (instance == null) 
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return instance._underlyingValue;
}
```

Comment: Should it perhaps be an `int?` implicit conversion so there doesn't need to be a magic value? Particularly if -1 could be a legitimate underlying value. I would think for situations like this you would either want to return null if the conversion isn't possible or throw an exception. (Obviously your answer fits the spec, so this is more of a questioning of the spec rather than the answer.)

Comment: @Anthony - In principle, I agree with you. In practice it is highly dependent on the class in question.

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyClass 
{
   public static implicit operator int(MyClass myClass) 
   {
      // code to convert from MyClass to int
   }
}
```

Take a look there : [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(VS.71).aspx) covers what you want exactly, should do the trick.